# How can I speed up Spring's form:options tag?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, tags

I'm using Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE.  I'm trying to render SELECT menus for country and state on my page, so I have

```
<form:select path="countries[${vs.index}]" cssClass="country">
    <form:option value="" label="Select Country" />
    <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" /> 
</form:select> 

<form:select path="states[${vs.index}]" cssClass="state">
    <form:option value="" label="Select State" />
    <form:options items="${stateList[vs.index]}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

There are about 239 country options and 50 state options, but yet the above two functions take about 11 seconds to render.  This is ridiculously slow, especially considering that data never changes.  Is there a way to speed this up or somehow get my application to cache these fragments?  I'm using Wildfly 11.0.0.Final and Java 8.

Comment: did you try @Cacheable(cacheNames = "countries") on top of countries method?

Comment: To clarify, the SQL query runs very quickly (< .2 seconds).  When I comment out the above code, my page renders quickly as well.  However, when the code is included, it takes a long time to run (render).

Comment: do you need to write it as jsp? i mean if it renders so long, i`d write something, that will prerender this info as html. If this suits you i can provide example

Comment: Why not loading them asynchronously using javascript?

Comment: @AlexG, My question is, why does it take so long?  Is it a bug with Spring?  Is it something I'm doing?  I woudl prefer to keep everything Spring for consistency unless I'm using their APIs incorrectly.

Comment: I am not quite pro with JSPs and spring tag library, but believe this is due to spring magic. As i know spring checks spring fields, convert types when needed and also for forms put every object in PageContext to allow children tags manipulate backed object. So this all should affect performance. Dont know tour achitecture, but JSP and Spring anyway contain html, so if you prefer you may not prerender, and just cache this info in another servlet, and then just load and insert into html. This may be not perfect solution, but 11 seconds still worse)

Comment: Actually your solution about caching and then re-rendering the cached HTML would be a great thing to do.  I mean, the first page load would suck, but subsequent page loads would be quick, so that's a solution I could live with.

Comment: @Dave I would imagine you still want to get to the route of the problem and it would help to see the country/state SQL-abstraction methods you're delegating to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it isn't what you are looking for, but why go to server for static list of countries (/states)?

You can easily write or use components for displaying such drop down in Javascript vanila or framework that will reduce network latency and also load.

Sending those list over network **for every client every page loading** seems awfully redundant and expansive.